# Rails and passing data to Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, maps

I have a view that lists all the states of US based on a certain condition. In the same view I have included an SVG map which picks up color based on the result set of states. The state list partial is mapped to a method A in my controller, while the JavaScript map is linked to a different method B in the same controller. However my method B needs to get the returned state lists from A. How can I share the variable between the two methods? 
I tried a `before_filter` method to load up some instance variables, but that didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
def reports
    @query   = @report.search_query
    @results = @query.results(:page => params[:page], :results_per_page => 200).hits
    @state = Array.new
    @results.each do |r|
        @state << r.result.state.abbreviation
    end
    @finalstate = @state.uniq 
end

def data
    state_groups = State.select('abbreviation,premium').inject({}) do |groups, state|
        groups["#{state.abbreviation}"] = {
            :abbreviation => state.abbreviation,
            :group => @finalstate.include?(state.abbreviation) ? "found" : "not",
            :clickable => "true"
        }
    groups
    end
    render :json => state_groups.to_json
end
```

In my partials I have something like this:

`content_for :footer_scripts do
  = javascript_bundle :bundle_report`

My JavaScript map involves the data method to get the JSON. This JSON returns a null, and that is where I am stuck.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Can you paste any code? That would help people answer your question. Its quite difficult to give you any advice without some more information.

Comment: Try this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: In my controller I have 2 methods, reports which returns a list of bills. I am using Solr to do this search function, and here I can find an unique array of states selected by this  query. This method is rendered via a partial "results.haml". The other method is data, which returns the same state list that I have found in results as a json object. The method data is invoked via an ajax call of a javascript that i also render in the same view. Does that explain it some ? Thanks